# Sugar Daddy wants to transfer money into my account and occasionally buy gifts for his customers..Am I being scammed?

Tags: money-transfer, sugar-daddy

I started talking with a guy and got into a sugar baby arrangement with him. He offered to pay off my credit card and pay me $800/weekly. I never gave him my bank info or anything related to me, but he gave me his bank info (account and routing number, etc). He asked me to go to the store to buy $900 worth of gift cards for 3 separate customers, which I stupidly did... I then spent the weekend arguing with him because he wanted me to buy more gift cards for customers, but I continuously refused because the money that was transferred hadn't hit my account yet so I didn't have any money. I contacted my bank this morning to let them know that the money was going to be transferred, but I wanted to make sure that I was taking every precaution since it was a large sum of money. I asked her to contact the guys bank and see if there were sufficient funds in the account so it wouldn't bounce and there were. The money finally reached my credit card today but I don't want to use my card at all until I know what is truly going on.

Comment: Hopefully you haven't given him any sugar because those gift cards are definitely not going to customers and you probably used some other victim's bank info to buy them.

Comment: Sounds like money laundering to me, and that could get you in serious legal trouble.

Comment: Voted to close as a duplicate. If you do a search on this site for "sugar baby" you'll see that this question comes up over and over again. Yes, you are being scammed. Their "payment" on your visa card will inevitably bounce, but it may take a few days or weeks for that to happen. You'll be left on the hook for any gift cards you bought, and possibly on the hook for fraud or money laundering charges as well. Stop all communication with these folks and contact your credit card company to let them know what's happened.

Comment: I need to sign up for gig except that I need it to be a Sugar Mommy who is  1/3 my age.  OK, maybe only 1/2 my age might be a better game plan so that she's not a 20+ year old and can formulate complete sentences ;->)

Comment: Unless you are having sex with the guy, it is virtually certain that you are being scammed.  Though of course having sex doesn't entirely eliminate the possibility of a scam.

Comment: Report the scam to the police and don't waste time to cry over spilled milk.

Comment: *Their "payment" on your visa card will inevitably bounce* it's dangerous to imply that bounced transfers are the indication that it was a scam. Many scams go undetected because they don't result in bounced funds. A common variant of this has the "daddy" providing the baby with stolen accounts, so it's *real* money and may never bounce. The baby buys gift cards as a way to launder the other victim's money. The other victim may have been tricked in a way that leaves them on the hook from the bank's perspective. The baby is left with no financial penalty and may not realize it's a scam.